# Как настроить nginx, чтобы он запросы с айпи из белого списка направлял на один хост, а от всех остальных на другой?

Tags: nginx, балансировка

У меня есть сервер (не web), который я запустил на разных двух хостах.
Так же есть белый список айпи адресов.
Я хочу, чтобы запросы с айпи из белого списка направлялись на один хост, а все остальные на другой.

Все запросы поступают на общий айпи:порт от nginx.

Как мне это настроить в nginx?

Comment: `proxy_pass http://$backend;`, переменную backend установить с помощью geo или map

Comment: @nörbörnën а как проверить наличие $remote_addr в списке внутри конфига nginx в секции map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить так: помощью директив [geo](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) или [map](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) назначаем переменной `$upstream_name` значение являющееся именем upstream и потом используем эту переменную в proxy_pass.

Пример (по памяти) сферической конфигурации в вакууме:

```
upstream backend0 {
    server  127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream backend1 {
    server  127.0.0.1:4000;
}

# вариант1
map $remote_addr $upstream_name {
    default           'backend1';
    '111.111.111.1'   'backend0';
}

# вариант2
geo $upstream_name {
    default           'backend1';
    111.111.111.1     'backend0';
}


server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://$upstream_name;
    }
}
```

> вариант с map мне нравится

возможно `geo` будет эффективнее при работе с ip-адресами.

> а если у меня очень большой список адресов? можно как-то вынести его в отдельный файл?

вынесите в отдельный файл сам `map` и подключите его директивой [include](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) в секции http.

стоит заранее увеличить значение директивы [map_hash_max_size](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map_hash_max_size) если вы решите использовать map и список будет *действительно* большим.

> и чтобы он динамически обновлялся. или командой его перезагружать, но
>   чтобы открытые соединения не закрывались

после обновления содержимого файла nginx-у нужно сообщить об обновлении конфигурации. делается это или чем-то из пускачей операционки `sudo service nginx reload` или сигналом [HUP](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/control.html). существующие соединения при этом не пострадают, но и новой конфигурации не получат.

Comment: вариант с map мне нравится. а если у меня очень большой список адресов? можно как-то вынести его в отдельный файл?
и чтобы он динамически обновлялся. или командой его перезагружать, но чтобы открытые соединения не закрывались

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук редиректить на разные порты nginx'у через ipset? А то и не nginx'у, а напрямик бэкенду.

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук не удобно на несколько вопросов отвечать в комментариях по этому я добавил всё в ответ

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev дело хорошее, если за использование nginx не стоит логика обработки других запросов. пишите ответ :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev я плохо понял ваш ответ. если это решит мою задачу, которую я описал в вопросе, тогда можно попросить вас описать подробнее про ipset

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук выгоднее использовать `geo` и заранее, при генерации файла, объединить адреса по маскам